# Cannot find DB#authenticate("username","password") method in mongo java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, jar

I am new to `mongo` and trying to learn it from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-hello-world-example/).

In this tutorial he is using

`boolean auth = db.authenticate("username", "password".toCharArray());`

However, I cannot find the `authenticate()` method while coding. I've looked into the [mongo 3.4 docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/) and cannot find the `authenticate()` method there too.

Can someone please help what I am missing or any other way to do it.

I am using `mongo-java-driver-3.4.2`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From the java documentation i can see com.mongodb.client with User Credentials parameter. Use that to create an instance of the mongo client.

Comment: mkyong tutorial is badly outdated, you should not follow it.

Comment: @1615903 Could you please suggest how to accomplish the above problem or can give some links

Comment: See [Connect to MongoDB](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/) and specifically the [Authentication](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/authentication/) sub-section. I would advise using the full [Tutorials](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/) section before you go following the blog posts you find on the internet. All from the "Official" documentation. Which is where you always should start.